# Is final String s = "Hello World" same as String s = "Hello World"?

Tags: java, string, class, final

If a class is defined as `final` and we declare an instance of the final class... Would it make any difference? or is `final` in such cases would be redundant?

```
final String s = "Hello World"
```

same as

```
String s = "Hello World"
```

Comment: `final` on a class and `final` on a variable/field are two different things

Comment: **Only reference is final** but still String object is also final as per String class.

Comment: final class - no subclasses. final variable/field - you can assign a value to it only once. final method - no override. So final in java is nothing like `const` in `c` or any other constant stuff you might heard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `final` on the variable, it means that it cannot be re-assigned. Consider the following example:

```
public class FinalExample {
    private final String a = "Hello World!"; // cannot be reassigned
    private String b = "Goodbye World!"; // can be reassigned

    public FinalExample() {
        a = b; // ILLEGAL: this field cannot be re-assigned
        b = a; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FinalExample();
    }
}
```

If you try to run it, you will get an error on `a=b`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The final field FinalExample.a cannot be assigned

    at FinalExample.<init>(FinalExample.java:7)
    at FinalExample.main(FinalExample.java:12)
```

Now, I think you were wondering whether it matters to have a `final` or not in front of the `String` data type specifically. Although you may have heard that `String` is immutable, you can still re-assign something like `String s = "Hello World!";` to another string value. This distinction is due to the fact that you are actually re-assigning the reference of `String s` to a new string. Therefore, the following is valid:

```
String s = "Hello World";
s = "Goodbye World!";
System.out.println(s);

Output: Goodbye World!
```

But you can use the `final` declaration to prevent this change:

```
final String s = "Hello World";
s = "Goodbye World!";
System.out.println(s);

Output: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The final local variable s cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment
```

The `final` declaration is great to use if you want to ensure that no one can change your `String` reference. You can use `final` for other data types as well to prevent the **reference** from being changed.

Answer (score 5):

`final` on a variable has **nothing** to do with whether the class is `final`.

```
final String s = "Hello World";
s = "Goodbye";  // illegal

String s2 = "Hello World";
s2 = "Goodbye";  // legal
```

Answer (score 4):

A final variable cannot be bound to another instance, so this is not valid:

```
final String s = "123";
s = "234"; // doesn't work!
```

A final class cannot be extended

```
final class A {
}

class B extends A { // does not work!
}
```

And both of this is not to be confused with [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) classes (like `String`). Instances of immutable classes won't change their state. (There is no direct language support for immutable classes, but in practice most of the time all attributes of immutable classes are declared final.)