# How to reference the class fromasubclass

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to find the answer but I can't. In java, when I create a subclass, how can I reffer the first level class? Using "this" accesses the subclass so I can't. The other option is passing the argument to the subclass but I'm curious if there is a simpliest method.

```
//here there is my other 1st level class implementation, this is a JFrame
btnNewProject.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            VehicleScreen pp=new VehicleScreen(**here should go the top class reference**);
                //v is a JPanel that I pass to allJframes
                v.setContentPane(pp);
                v.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: try super.topVariable

Comment: take a look at the `super` keyword

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve... can you try to clarify your problem?

Comment: can´t "Syntax error on super delete this token". already tried it, the problem is that I want to access the whole reference of the object not a single attribute (that I cando withouththe need of super). I mean, I want to acces inside the subclass the reference of the top object, lets say my top class is named A, so I want to pass to my subclass B (the new ActionListener) the reference of A.

Comment: Do you want to access `v`? Then set it `final`.

Comment: This seems like it might be a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/155831).  What is it the code is trying to achieve, explicitly?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Foo {
  int x;

  Foo() {
    new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        Foo.this.x = 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple choices:

1. Make the variable outside the anonymous class an instance variable:

   ```
   public class AnonymousClass extends JFrame {
       private JLabel label;
       ...

       public AnonymousClass() {
       ...
           btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   label.setText(textField.getText());
               }
           });
       ...
       }
   ```

   You can also access the instance variable as follows:

   ```
   AnonymousClass.this.label.setText(textField.getText());
   ```
2. Use the `final` modifier on the local variable:

   ```
   public class AnonymousClass extends JFrame {
       ...

       public AnonymousClass() {
       final JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter a new message!");
           btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   label.setText(textField.getText());
               }
           });
       ...
       }
   ```

   Be aware that using the [`final` modifier will mean you cannot re-assign the variable at a later point in your program.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24024987/2557554)